# When deploying to Next JS api to Vercel the css files of a module are removed. How to avoid it?

Tags: css, next.js, swagger-ui, vercel, tree-shaking

I need to access a css file of a node_modules package to create swagger documentation inside an endpoint from the Next API.

Tree shaking is being done, so the css files from the swagger-ui-dist package are removed. How to avoid it? I tried to use "sideEffects" in next.config.js webpack key, but still the css file disappeared.

EDIT: I now know and correct me if I am wrong that tree shaking is done by Vercel

Answer (score 0):

to avoid having the css files removed, you can add a "sideEffects" property to your `package.json` file and define the CSS files you do not want to be removed. For example:

```
"sideEffects": [
  "node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css"
]
```

Comment: I did it, doesn't work because as I said vercel does the tree shaking, not me